# How to achieve pagination in a single request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I am working on a ruby on rails application. I am using `will_paginate` gem to achieve pagination in results.

But with each new page, a new request is sent and all the processing in the controller is done again.

I want to know if I can achieve pagination in such a way that request to the backend is sent only once and the results are displayed accordingly in pages.

Answer (score 3):

This more has to do with the front-end, since a change of page would imply changing the DOM of your page (that requires JavaScript). So, the short answer is:

#### **"No, why would you want that?"**

Think of this: **pagination is usually involved in cases, when the dataset is too large** to display on one page. It might be difficult to comprehend for the end-user (and possibly his hardware), might be too large for network bandwidth given the amount of users or could be subject to change in the middle of a transmission (and therefore be invalid for quite some time after having been recieved).

The case you want to achieve seems to be **similar to disabling pagination at all**, that's at least how it looks on the back-end: thansfer all your data in one large chunk and let the client paginate it. I've seen cases when a server dropped a 500 (Internal Server Error) with large datasets, because it was unable to render a view of size that huge.

Well... I hope I've made it clear that it should only be done in cases when it wouldn't cause harm, which is in most cases highly probable. Assuming you know what you're doing, [here's an example](http://listjs.com/examples/pagination) of how it could be done. It's not about the backend at all.

As an alternative, you could load data in chunks asynchronously, Mostly client-side again, only with the difference that server-side pagination stays in place.

But you seem to be avoiding certain controller action to be executed entirely when browsing the dataset. That is, you could call a certain action on when a **dataset is accessed** that does its job and then **redirects** to paginating action that contains direct (non-redirecting) links to other pages.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `will_paginate` and Rails for that at all.

You need to load all records on your first request and implement JavaScript pagination

Of course, there are lots of libraries you could use